# What is the origin of the Hero's Journey?

Tags: structure, hero

I'm curious as to whether or not there was one story seen as the 'first' example of the Hero's Journey.

Most Googling returns academic theory (Campbell's steps) rather than examples. But I'm curious if there are any early stories from either East or West culture that contain the basic story structure and laid the foundations for later examples.

We could cite the story of Krishna (and later the story of Christ) for examples of death/resurrection or later Lord of the Rings for a very typical journey structure, but I'm wondering if there are any examples that were popular/influential in making the structure end up being repeated so often? (e.g. as the damsel in distress trope was popularised in part by King Kong, and Star Wars took existing character archetypes and put them into forms repeated in other media)

Comment: Your assertion that "Star Wars codified character archetypes into repeatable trends" is incorrect. Lucas *used* already existing archetypes to write a story which was so universal. The entire point of Campbell's book *Hero with a Thousand Faces* was that these steps and archetypes date back as far as people have told stories. The monomyth in and of itself may not be universal, but many varying bits and pieces appear across cultures.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum By 'codified' I meant Lucas put it in a popular form that has been copied, not that he created it (poor word choice on my part). Possibly this question is too broad for a single answer?

Comment: I'd look into the original fairy tales. They seem to be innocent on screen, but the origin stories have absolute masterpieces hidden in them. I suggest researching them.

Comment: No, Lucas did not. What is being copied is ***Campbell's*** codification, that is where the academic work was done, including stories from five and as much as ten thousand years ago, and it is what Lucas used. A copy of Lucas is a copy of a copy of Campbell, it is not fair to give Lucas credit for something he did not do. He simply created another story from Campbell's template, he did NOT create a new template.

Comment: It was Christopher Vogler that codified the Hero's Journey for Hollywood, not George Lucas. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Vogler Star Wars was the great exemplar of the method, but it was Vogler who introduced the method.

Comment: @MarkBaker Vogler wrote that book in 2007. Unless Lucas also has a TARDIS, I fail to see how *Star Wars,* which debuted in 1977, could have benefited from Vogler's work.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum I was not meaning to imply that he did. Lucas used the hero's journey (which he learned from Campbell, IIRC) but it was Vogler who codified it as standard Hollywood practice (citing Star Wars as well as other classic films), first in the celebrated memo and later in the book. We talk about hero's journey today largely because of Vogler, not Lucas.

Comment: The Hero's Journey being such an old structure, you might try just looking for the oldest known stories of mankind and see which fits the narrative. Maybe start out with the Epic of Gilgamesh.

Comment: A simple wikipedia search would have helped: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero's_journey The "monomyth" was studied by anthropologists who looked into popoular tales, fairytales, myths and oral tradition.

Comment: Just looking at the myth and legend stories... Achilles/Troy, Hercules, King Arthur, are just a few examples of popular stories that have been told for ages that fit the hero's journey plot. Star Wars didn't do anything to revolutionize this plot. You can argue though that the only thing star wars did is change the role in which women play in action/epic stories where they typically were cast for eye candy. Princess Leia broke that barrier or at least helped push women film role in a more positive direction.

Answer (score 3):

That first story is long lost in the mists of time. Indeed, it could reasonably argued that it is the first and universal story. In a very real sense, this is the story written in the human heart, and the art of the storyteller is not creating this story but discovering and serving the need that exists in our natures.

There is far far too much emphasis on originality today. This is ironic given that we live in an age in which it seems that every vein of art has been so thoroughly explored that there is really nothing new left to invent, discover, or exploit. But perhaps that is why we are so concerned with originality.

If we regard art as a response to a fundamental need of the human heart, however, we realize that originality is bosh. There is no part of the human heart that remains to be explored by artists, no new ground to be exploited. The value of art lies not in its originality, but in its poignancy, its pointedness, and its ability to feed the universals of the human heart in the guise of particular modern sensibilities.

I hate to come back to the same examples, but in the interests of illustrating the point with a universal reference point, Harry Potter is a hugely derivative work. (If you did not grow up in the tradition of classic English children's literature you might not recognize all of its derivations, but if you have, they are plain as day.) But it's being derivative is not a complaint against it. (I have other complaints, but they are not germane to the point here.) What virtues it has, which account for its enormous popularity, lie in interpreting ancient tropes for modern readers.

In short, we are not in the telling business, but in the retelling business. Our job is not to break new ground, but to make ancient ground accessible to modern audiences, to tell again the ancient tales for modern ears.

The hero's journey is the story. The only story. It is told a million times. Our job is to tell it again.